# Is there a mathematical term for the "de-peaking" of a dataset

Tags: graphing-functions, transformation

I have several sets of data that exhibit similar "peaks" when viewed as a graph, e.g.:

[image: Peaked data]

A more useful representation of this data (for my purposes) is ${y = abs(x - 70)}$. The representation of the above chart using this method is below: 
[image: De-peaked data]

Essentially, I want the x with the highest y value to be x=0, and x values with decreasing y values to be ${x > 0}$

Comment: I would call that operation ($x\to|x-a|$) a "folding" of the plot, but this is not specific to your context of removing a side of the maximum. I would certainly not say "depeaking" as the peak is still there.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, as you say, it is a "folding", I just wanted to check if there was a technical term. What is ${a}$ in your above equation?

Comment: Hem, $70$ probably.

Comment: Ah, I see its the same as the one I was using - just wanted to check that it wasn't a value with a specific meaning, just the max(y).

Comment: @YvesDaoust : so you understood his question ?

Comment: @user1952009: I think so, is that bad ? ;)